# Parsing the result from the result - php

Tags: php, laravel, curl, postmates

How can i get the value of fee in this response

I am integrating the postman api in the php application, for that i am using a curl call from php,

here is the code

```
<?php

class PostMates extends Controller {

public function getDeliveryQuote()
    {
            $url = "https://api.postmates.com/v1/customers/cus_XX/delivery_quotes";

    $uname = "70538e7";
    $pwd = "xxxx";

    $process = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Accept: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $uname . ":" . $pwd);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "dropoff_address=20 McAllister St, San Francisco, CA 94102&pickup_address=101 Market St, San Francisco, CA 94105");
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $return = curl_exec($process);

    curl_close($process);

    //var_dump($return);
    print_r($return);


    }

}
```

While i do print_r and var_dump, below given is the response.

How can i get the fee amount from the resonse.

I tried like $response->fee and $resonse['fee'], but i don't get the result.

How can i get it . Help pls

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Sun, 28 Feb 2016 18:26:14 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d7e72569c2358ea8636fac1a1054815081456683973; expires=Mon, 27-Feb-17 18:26:13 GMT; path=/; domain=.postmates.com; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
CF-RAY: 27be2d3566b42fd5-MAA

{"kind": "delivery_quote", "fee": 750, "created": "2016-02-28T18:26:14Z", "expires": "2016-02-28T18:31:14Z", "currency": "usd", "duration": 60, "dropoff_eta": "2016-02-28T19:31:14Z", "id": "dqt_KhBvlVTh8vQ8N-"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ya go. You have to parse the results.

```
$result = json_decode($result,true); //decodes JSON to associative array

echo $result['fee']; //750
```

Alternatively, if you want to use an object format

```
$result = json_decode($result); //decodes JSON to an object

echo $result->fee; //750
```

**EDIT**

You also need to set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `false`

This includes response header in output

```
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
```

Comment: thanks, but i am alwasy getting `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: ah, so that's the actual $request contents compared to the curl verbose. ouput that changes things -- check my answer's edit for the other half of the answer